# "Failed to get global data: No buffer space available" on running "systemd-resolve --status"

Tags: dns, systemd-resolved

I'm on Mint 20.3 (based on Ubuntu 20.04) and I keep having this weird problem where my network is all working fine and then suddenly, apparently out of the blue, it stops working and I can't access any websites.  It's not my browser because the same happens using `curl`.

I found a thread that mentioned using `systemd-resolve --status` to get the current status of DNS.  That command ran fine when the network was OK, and I saved a copy to compare with the output when the network was playing up.

However, now the network is playing up again, I've run the command again and is output is an error: `Failed to get global data: No buffer space available`.  I've searched for a solution but nothing seems to mention `systemd-resolve`, so I'm at a loss as to what's going on.

[This answer](https://serverfault.com/a/901347/251378) gave me some hope, but I increased the buffer size to twice what's mentioned, and it had no effect.

Anyone got any ideas, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It comes from this part of the source code:
`resolve/resolvectl.c`

```
  1843  
  1844          r = bus_map_all_properties(bus,
  1845                                     "org.freedesktop.resolve1",
  1846                                     "/org/freedesktop/resolve1",
  1847                                     property_map,
  1848                                     BUS_MAP_BOOLEAN_AS_BOOL,
  1849                                     &error,
  1850                                     &m,
  1851                                     &global_info);
  1852          if (r < 0)
  1853                  return log_error_errno(r, "Failed to get global data: %s", bus_error_message(&error, r));
  1854
```

I checked in what cases systemd would report ENOBUFS, and you seemingly only get this error when you've filled up the pending send or receive buffers for DBUS.

The underlying error (`ENOBUFS`) occurs in the a DBUS internal library request.

Its an internal buffer you cannot increase the size of, but its undoubtedly an indication that DBUS (or the underlying library) has stopped responding to requests, up until the internal buffer has filled up and it gives up adding more data to it, returning `ENOBUFS` instead.

I would consider checking your systemd DBUS. Perhaps its stopped, crashed or become stuck somehow.

Comment: Thanks so much for taking a look at this.  You certainly seem to be correct: when I do `sudo systemctl status dbus.service` I get lots of lines telling me "The maximum number of active connections for UID 1000 has been reached (max_connections_per_user=256)".  I can't restart the dbus service, however (it tells me it's configured to refuse manual start/stop) and I don't know how to determine why there are so many active connections or what those connections are!  Any suggestions...?

Comment: I _think_ I've got it...!  [This article](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/438023), and specifically the attached python script, showed me that I had an absurd number of connections relating to `upower`, which in turn led me to realise that a power monitoring script I'd written was inadvertently leaving `upower -m` processes running when I thought they were being aborted.  I've now fixed that, and will keep an eye on it to make sure the issue is fixed; then I'll come back and mark this as the answer.  Thanks again!